# .NET Core project does not automatically reference net40 library in NuGet package

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget

In .NET Core projects, you don't have explicit references to assemblies within a NuGet package. Instead, you just have this snippet in your project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="PackageName" Version="1.2.3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

and the .NET Core toolchain is expected to take care of downloading/installing the package then referencing the correct assembly within. However, that isn't working for me in this case.

I am working to bundle a library into a NuGet package. This is a .NET Framework 4.0 library. I also have a .NET Core 2.1 project which references this library. This works fine with an explicit assembly reference, no issues detected from testing and the [.NET Portability Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) gives the library a perfect score.

When I bundle the library into a NuGet package in the lib/net40 directory then add a reference to the package from my .NET Core 2.1 project, the project does not auto-reference the library as expected. I have to put the library in a lib/netstandard2.0 directory for the auto-reference to work. I don't want to do this, because the library is not in fact a .NET Standard 2.0 library.

How can I override the .NET Core auto-reference behavior to reference the library in the lib/net40 directory? I've found [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/third-party-deps#net-framework-compatibility-mode) on .NET Framework compatibility mode for NuGet packages referenced from .NET Core projects, but I'm guessing it only applies to net45 and above.

Comment: you're trying to reference a .net library from a .net core only library?

Comment: Yes, with the .NET Standard 2.0 compatibility shim this works quite well. The assembly reference itself works just fine when tested alone. The issue is the auto-reference isn't working with a NuGet package containing that same library.

Comment: The "compatibility shim" is really not a feature you should rely on. As package reference is a feature of MSBuild, you might open an issue on GitHub to see what is the cause, https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues